# Difference between .COM and .EXE

Tags: c

I have com across an article which states that `.COM` files are better for small application than `.EXE` files. What are `.COM` files?   How do we create a `.COM` file? How are they better than `.EXE` files? I also want to know whether `.COM` files are still widely used?

Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did this article come from 1985? [COM files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file#MS-DOS_binary_format) are long dead, as they are DOS only, may only be 64 KiB big and have many other issues.

They used to be a much simpler format then EXE, as you could create a valid com executable with a few lines in [debug.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEBUG.EXE) or an assembler. I am getting a little bit nostalgic here...

Comment: That's 64K for code *and* data, if I recall correctly. And I was thinking "old magazine" as well.

Comment: Exchange 2010 comes with a setup.com, so they're not *that* dead!

Comment: Ben, are the first two byte of this setup.com 'MZ' by chance? This would mean it's really an exe file.

Comment: @SvenW - yes they are in fact, I stand corrected. At the time I did think it was a bit odd and outdated (especially since Server 2008 R2 and Exchange 2010 are both only 64 bit) but I didn't really think that much more of it.

Answer (score 0):

COM files is great, because you can convert executable magically to text files. 
EXE files does always have a MZ header while COM doesn't. As you can generate code dynamically in x86 arch, you can generate binary opcodes using opcodes in printable chars.

Here is an example, program README.COM:

```
P5CQ5sPP[X5iK4iH4]P_1?CC5IQ5CBP_1?SX4v4pPZ5iH5i@okey
Text2COM example by 谢继雷 (Lenik).
$
```

In this example, the bootstrap opcodes generate a DOS INT 21H interrupt to display a string terminated by '$'.

Some old time compilers may have some options to support .COM file, but since it's 16-bit executable, they haven't been supported for many years.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!  Can you elaborate on this some?  Perhaps point me towards some documentation how you wrote your program there?

Comment: Well, ... 诀窍就在于不停的尝试，首先你手头必须有份机器码对照表，然后不停的转动你的脑筋，因为不是每个指令都能用，你只能挑选那些代码凑巧是字母的指令，组合、尝试、如此反复即可。有时候这要靠运气，不过更多的是需要耐心。

Comment: The trick is to keep trying, first of all you must have taken the machine code table on hand, and then rotated in your brain, because not every command can be used, you can only choose that code happens to be a letter of instruction, combined Try, and so forth can be. Sometimes it depends on luck, but more of a need to be patient.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks!  And +1 for giving me an answer in Chinese as well. :) 你真棒！谢谢！而一给我一个答复，以及中国。：）