# Creating a COM file from text

Tags: windows, com, assembly, ascii

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326594/difference-between-com-and-exe/3327303#3327303) is a pretty awesome trick.  Just for my own edification, I'd like to learn to create that type of program.

Is there a nice library that I can use to ensure my output is entirely ASCII?  Or what tools would I begin to use to generate that type of output?  I understand that I would likely be creating a 16-bit application, but can I generate 32-bit applications as well?

I've found MSFT's `debug.exe` program has an assembler that works with this, but the output I receive from that is not entirely ASCII.  Also, when disassembling the program provided in 谢继雷'Lenik's answer I don't see where he calls `int 21` to write to the screen.  Is there more documentation somewhere for this type of program?

Can anyone else me sort out these mysteries, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text-to-com file is a very neat trick.  It takes advantage of the fact that the 16-bit loader will load the image at offset 0x0100 and start executing at that address.

An exe file includes a [binary header](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65122) that cannot be represented as text.  As a result, you can't create a 32-bit or 64-bit executable that is strictly text.

Comment: Excellent, that's great to know about the 32- and 64-bit executables.  But can you provide me some resources on creating a 16- application that is entirely ASCII?

Comment: @mrduclaw: Basically, the program in the example you linked is a bootstrap loader that decodes the text that follows to create the code that's eventually executed.  I don't have the time to sit down and work out exactly how he did it.  But you can load the program in debug.exe and single-step it to see what's happening.

Comment: It's just a simple XOR-encoding of INT 21 INT 20

Answer (score 4):

A classical example of a .COM file using only printable characters is [EICAR](http://eicar.org/anti_virus_test_file.htm), a file used to test antivirus. Some time ago, there was a [discussion thread about EICAR](http://archive.cert.uni-stuttgart.de/bugtraq/2003/06/msg00251.html) at bugtraq.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really a "trick" here, except for careful use of machine code that happens to all map to ASCII characters. I'm not in a position to disassemble that code at the moment, but 谢继雷'Lenik indicates that that there is some self-modifying code involved.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  So no resources to help generate such code; just lots of trial and error? Or any resources on just writing 16-bit DOS assembly would be awesome too (for instance, creating/writing to files, etc).

Answer (score 2):

In the day of MSDOS programs, simple programs were written using assembly, or maybe compiled and linked to .COM—though that was not as common as assembling directly to .COM.

To know what to do (pre-www) one obtained two or three reference books, including [Peter Norton's *Programmer's Guide to the IBM PC*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Norton), aka ''The Pink Shirt Book''.

*Ralf Brown's Interrupt List* is a reasonable substitute and is online [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/).

Unless you have an old computer available, it might be challenging to find a valid execution environment for an MSDOS .COM file.

Comment: Windows XP (or earlier) should still contain an NTVDM that can run COM files.

Comment: @Greg:  Agreed—that would be an *old computer*.

Comment: Ok, my work computer was upgraded from XP to 7 about a month ago. :)